# Looking for a system for creative people with little time

Tags: game-recommendation, fate, dungeon-world, cypher-system, genesys

Which system allows creativity for masters and players while cutting time on preparing and studying rules? However, it should still have rules and material.

I tried FATE and Savage Worlds. Liked FATE much more. But still not completely happy. Some things in FATE can be confusing or need a lot of preparation. Also, it seems that there are little guidance and rules to some areas I would like.

I like the system behind Numenera (Cypher System), but Numenera is too hard to grasp for some persons. Is Cypher without Numenera a viable option?

I heard good about the system behind the new Star Wars RPG (Genesys) and Dungeon World. Are they worth a look or buy?

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you have time you can take the [tour] to find out more about the site. Unfortunately, game recommendations are unsuited to our stack format but we do have a [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33707) where you can ask this kind of question.

Comment: Try the RPG sub on Reddit. There is a constant flow of recommendation questions.

Comment: Consider trying Paranoia: Troubleshooters by Mongoose Publishing. Prep time is minimal for everyone except the GM. Rules are simple and don't require a lot of reading (unless you are the GM).
Genesys is also worth looking into.